# Regex value between sequence 1 and final occurrence of sequence 2

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`s = {u\'main\': u\'SNEAK THIEVES GET $3,200.; Members of "The Girl From Maxim\'s" Company Lose $1,200.\'}`

I'm trying to match only the section, which looks like this:

`SNEAK THIEVES GET $3,200.; Members of "The Girl From Maxim\'s" Company Lose $1,200.` 
in python.

Using the following regex:

`re.search(r"(?<=\:\su\').*?(?=\')", s)`

I've managed to capture a part of the string:

`SNEAK THIEVES GET $3,200.; Members of "The Girl From Maxim`

As you can tell, this is incomplete because the `\'` sequence occurs more than once in my string.

Is it somehow possible for me to capture all text between the first instance of a particular sequence (this part I've managed) and the the **final** instance of a sequence which occurs multiple times?

*TLDR, simplified*

given `string = AAA BBB DD DD DD`, is it possible to capture everything between sequence `AAA` and the **final occurrence** of sequence `DD`?

Comment: How about the greedy variant `(?<=\\':\su\\').*(?=\\')`  (additionally corrected and with escaped backslashes)? [Test](https://regex101.com/r/hzHESf/1).

Comment: `.*?` is lazy, matching as few chars as possible. `.*` is greedy, matching as many as possible.